# Edit a single column in Gridview using dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to add a dropdown control in a single column.The dropdownlist value will be declared on the presentation layer

[image]

I just want  a dropbox in `User_Status` so that i can chnage the status and when i click on a save button , the changes get saved to the database

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
      <asp:GridView  ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"   runat="server"   BackColor="White" BorderColor="#808080" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGenerateEditButton ="true"
              CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical"  
            AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4"   >
      </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: u need  templatefield

Answer (score 0):

here use a template field

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDataBound="grdView4_OnRowDataBound" CssClass="Grid table table-hover table-bordered" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView4_SelectedIndexChanged">
                 <Columns>
                   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownlist runat="server">
                     </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                  </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```